# I set the style to move but the image won't move

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm just trying to add an image to a webpage in the space I want in. In asp.net core application I type:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
   <img src="~/css/Koala.jpg" class="profile" height="100">
}
```

The image appears when the user signs in but I think its too far to the left so I add this to the CSS:

```
.profile { 
   position: relative;
   top: 20px;
   left: 100px;
}
```

But the image didn't move?

I've tried using ID's and double checked I'm referencing the right style sheet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting `.profile`'s `position` to `absolute` and setting it's container to `relative`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ended up fixing the problem is you have to add the type before an id. for example

p#profoile{} another problem i had was also just the input was being cached

Comment: you also may need to do ctrl + f5 to adequate refresh so your browser doesnt cache the css